# Object returned on mysql_num_rows() function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a login script with prepared statements in PHP procedural mysqli syntax. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
include "/ssincludes/functions.php";
$host = HOST;
$username = USER;
$password = PASSWORD;
$db_name = DATABASE;
$table = TABLEU;
//These includes and constants are fine I checked them all
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }   
$myusername='test';
$mypassword='password1';

$sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_name=? and password=?";
$result=mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 'ss', $myusername, $mypassword);
mysqli_execute($result);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($result);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $row_cnt;
?>
```

The error returned is: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given

I thought I took out all instances of OO PHP in my script? Also I understand that this may mean my query is incorrect so I ran it on MySQL in the database and all seems to be fine there:

[image]

So I am lost as to what the problem could be. I read many similar posts (maybe I'm missing one that is exactly similar to mine) and none seem to handle the problem. I appreciate your time and help.

P.S. I understand the security issues with plain text passwords and using "password1". I plan to use better security practices as I build this but I just want to get prepared statements down first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
mysqli_stmt_execute
mysqli_stmt_num_rows
```

Instead of the `mysqli_execute` and `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: I should also add that your helped me figure out a better syntax which actually compared the input with the DB and make it do what I need. I had use `mysqli_stmt_init`, `mysql_stmt_prepare` and also `mysql_stmt_store_result` needed to be before I got the row count. After that my row count wasn't zero! Big Thanks!